# C++ constexpr math (header-only) library

Tags: library, software-development, c++, math

I'd like to utilize C++14's constexpr semantics expansion to calculate some mathematical formulae at compile time. But - I don't want to "roll my own" constexpr versions of `sqrt()`, `log()`, `sin()` etc. It's not that I couldn't do it, it's just that it would be reinventing the wheel.

So has anyone published such a library?

**Notes:**

- Must be platform-independent.
- No Boost dependencies please.
- It should be C++14-based; just C++11 would make for a rather contrived implementation.
- Since we're talking about constexpr here, it should be portable and the hardware and OS details shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Need details of which platform, CPU, OS, etc., to possibly answer.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: It's constexpr stuff - I'm just looking for a bunch of .hpp files; why would any of those details matter?

Comment: It matters because, for example, any assembly "shortcuts" will be cpu specific.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: `#ifdef CAN_TAKE_SHORTCUT shortcut_code; #else regular_code; #endif` ... anyway, removed the text about assembly tricks.

Answer (score 1):

#### GCEM - Generalized constexpr Math

by Keith O'Hara

Websites: [Main site](https://www.kthohr.com/gcem.html) |  [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/kthohr/gcem/).

- C++11
- Template-oriented
- Last release: [1.12.0](https://github.com/kthohr/gcem/releases/tag/v1.12.0), May 2019
- Updated occasionally

Additional features of interest, from the library's website:

- Continued fraction expansions and series expansions are implemented using recursive templates.
- The `gcem::` syntax is identical to the C++ standard library (`std::`).
- Tested and accurate to floating-point precision against the C++ standard library.
- Released under a permissive (non-GPL) license.

Caveat:

- I haven't tried it.
- If it's C++11-based, there may be performance issues (w.r.t. compilation time)

Answer (score 1):

### Sprout

*"C++11/14 constexpr based Containers, Algorithms, Random numbers, Parsing, Ray tracing, Synthesizer, and others."*

by Bolero Murakami (I think that's the name)

Websites: [Main site](http://bolero-murakami.github.io/Sprout/) |  [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/bolero-MURAKAMI/Sprout).

- C++11
- No releases, use the master branch
- Updated rarely
- Boost Software License

Caveats:

- I haven't tried it.
- If it's C++11-based, there may be performance issues (w.r.t. compilation time)
- Seems a bit like overkill for just constexpr math

Answer (score -1):

If you are using gcc to compile your C++ 11 then there is the [GCC python plugin](https://gcc-python-plugin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which you may be able to do what you need with.

The python gcc plugin allows you to use the full power of python as a part of your gcc compile & build process. Given that python provides full maths libraries, *basic by default and very advanced from numpy*, and this plugin lets you access gcc internals you should be able to perform almost any compile time calculations that you can imagine.

Comment: That's not what I asked for. I don't want to "use the power of python", I want to be able to use some more expressive math for compile-time computations.

Comment: python provides expressive and comprehensive calculations.

Comment: I'm sure it does, it's  just not what I'm looking for. It won't allow help me instantiate an `std::array` at a length being the square root of something.

Comment: @einpoklum - it might be worth adding that _and a couple more examples_ plus which compiler you are using, etc., to your question to try to get it reopened as that is the sort of question details that are being looked for.